# Parse json object in php

Tags: json

The json code is as follows as :

> ```
> {"data":[
> {"data":
> {"created":"2014-02-26T21:14:56.662Z",
> "district":"4fd43cc56d11340000000005",
> "high_grade":"12",
> "last_modified":"2014-02-26T21:14:56.665Z",
> "location":{"address":"350 5th Avenue","city":"New York","state":"NY","zip":"10001"},
> "low_grade":"9",
> "name":"Clever High School",
> "nces_id":"360008000000",
> "phone":"(212) 555-1212",
> "principal":{"name":"TheodoraKhan","email":"tdkhan@mailinator.com"},
> "school_number":"02M800",
> "sis_id":"02M800",
> "state_id":"712345","id":"530e595026403103360ff9fd"},
> "uri":"/v1.1/schools/530e595026403103360ff9fd"},
>
> {"data":{"created":"2014-02-26T21:14:56.668Z","district":"4fd43cc56d11340000000005","high_grade":"5","last_modified":"2014-02-26T21:14:56.670Z","location":{"address":"110
> ```
>
> Pineapple
>   Street","city":"Brooklyn","state":"NY","zip":"11201"},"low_grade":"Kindergarten","name":"Clever
>   Elementary School","nces_id":"360007000000","phone":"(718)
>   555-4567","principal":{"name":"Cecilia
>   Roderick","email":"ceciliar@mailinator.com"},"school_number":"13K123","sis_id":"13K123","state_id":"30890","id":"530e595026403103360ff9fe"},"uri":"/v1.1/schools/530e595026403103360ff9fe"}

Comment: `@user3291422` can you verify the JSON? [Validated Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9337256c884577d65585)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are asking.

But you can use the following:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

Comment: If not sure, why not asking as an comment and answering only when you are sure. Isn't this what the stackoverflow is?

Comment: @Nabin It's a poorly worded question, but my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$data = {"data":"a"}:
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->data;
```